# interface on linux bridge not coming up

Tags: networking, ethernet, reboot, interface

I have a linux bridge named mybridge and interfaces connected on it named ens38,ens39 and ens40. The output of /etc/network/interfaces is as follows

```
auto mybridge
iface mybridge inet manual
bridge_ports ens38 ens39 ens40
```

the ethernet port ens38 is bridged to a physical ethernet port on my server. Only this port ens38 does not come up automatically on reboot and the rest of the interfaces come up automatically. If i do

```
ifconfig ens38 up
```

everything is fine. How can I make sure this interface also come up automatically on reboot

Comment: more context please. what do you do to otherwise make it come back up? reboot on host or on client causes loss of this info? are there other ways to provoke this loss?

Comment: Hi Tatsu. If I do ifconfig ens38 up, the interface comes up and the networking is completed. If I reboot again, the interface is not up.